# "MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeros due to CORS access restrictions" while loading local mp3 file

Tags: javascript

I know there are numerous similar threads inquiring about the same problem but mine is loading a locally stored mp3 file on my computer. Site is not hosted, I'm entirely working the set up offline.

I'm following the tutorial posted below to create an audio analyser: http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Analyser-Bars-Animation-HTML-Audio-API-Tutorial

I have already changed the deprecated webkit functions. The crossOrigin = "anonymous" does not work and I don't think it is relevant as my file is hosted locally. **Setting the crossOrigin to "anonymouse" gets rid of the error but the play button is greyed out.** There are no script errors, just the CORS access problem outlined in the title. Here is the complete javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/kshatriiya/p8u5h3dz/

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'track1.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
    context = new webkitAudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
    analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper(){
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // Color of the bars
    bars = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
        //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your markup?

Comment: @vvtx sure, here is the jsfiddle, I haven't loaded a track though as the file is on my hd: https://jsfiddle.net/kshatriiya/p8u5h3dz/

Answer (score 0):

> Site is not hosted, I'm entirely working the set up offline.

Most browsers treat all `file:` URIs as being of different origins. There isn't much you can do about that.

> I plan to eventually host the site so I won't be working offline always

Do this now. It is how you solve the problem. Install a local web server and use that for development.